# CentOS 5.7 access system call returns EACCES when apache web server checks for file existence

Tags: php, c++, linux, centos

Here is our Centos Version number

```
[marc disk5]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
```

Here is how we start our apache web server

```
[marc php]$ sudo gdb /usr/sbin/httpd
[sudo] password for marc: 
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-37.el5_7.1)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/httpd...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run -X
```

Here is how we start our firefox web browser

```
[marc]$ sudo firefox
[sudo] password for marc:
```

Here is the URL we enter into firefox web browser

```
http MatchUpObjectPHPSample.php
```

When we activate the submit request on the web page rendered by the web browser,we get the following diagnostic messages:

```
Path /home/marc/data/mdMatchup.dat
throw exception /home/marc/data/mdMatchup.dat retval -1 errno 13
```

Errno 13 IS EACCESS which is returned by the C/C++ access("/home/marc/data/mdMatchup.dat",F_OK) API call which we use to test for 
file existence. THe man page for access states that:

> EACCES The requested access would be denied to the file or search permission is denied for one of the directories in the path prefix of pathname.

Here is our path permissions:

```
[marc /]$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Jan  3 11:45 home

[marc home]$ ls -l
drwx------ 38 marc     users 4096 May 29 16:36 marc

[marc home]$ cd marc
[marc ~]$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root       4096 May 29 19:20 data

[marc ~]$ cd data
[marc data]$ pwd
/home/marc/data
[marc data] ls -l 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 244736 May 28 15:49 mdMatchup.dat
```

Finally, here is a very short snippet of C++ code:

```
cSQLite::cSQLite(char *File_,bool bMustExist_) {
  int retval(0);

  if (bMustExist_) {
     retval = access(File_,F_OK);

     if (retval != 0) {
       printf("throw exception %s retval %d errno %d\n",File_,retval,errno);
       throw cException(ERR_DBDATABASE,"cSQLite",File_);
     }

     if (sqlite3_open(File_,&Database)!=SQLITE_OK) {
       RecordError();
       throw cException(ERR_DBDATABASE,"cSQLite",LastError);
     }
  }

  Statement=0;
  Columns=0;
}
```

Could someone tell us what mistakes we are making, or if this is CentOS version specific problem?

Comment: Did you check your /etc/sudoers file? You may not have the permissions on `marc` that you think. You may have a goofy Runas_Spec or whatever.

Comment: @jnbbneder, I just checked the /etc/sudoers file. Here are the relevant lines: root ALL=(ALL) ALL marc ALL=(ALL) ALL. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Why are you starting up httpd directly instead of using the standard startup scripts? Why are you running the browser as root? root permissions don't travel over an HTTP connection?

Beyond that, the problem is that your `marc` directory is readable only by the `marc` user. Apache, by design, will drop root permissions and run as a non-privileged user (httpd, htdata, etc...), so it will NOT have the rights to access anything in /home/marc.

Comment: I tried using the standard startup scripts and running the browser as marcuser, In addition, I chown-ed the /home/marc subtree to apache user and user group but access(path,F_OK) still returns -1 with errno EACCESS. I am running yum update on the Centos server right now as I remember that Red Hat Linux 4.0 did not have this access problem . Thank you for your help.